# Minimize sum of squared euclidean norms

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

Let $A_{ij}$ be a `9 * 1` vector of known values, let $x$ be a `3 * 9` matrix of unknowns and let $b_{ij}$ be a `3 * 1` vector, where `0 < i < m, 0 < j < n`. My question is how to solve:
$$ 
min_x \sum_{i,j}|| x A_{ij} - b_{ij}||_2^2
$$
I have been reading a [research paper](http://lgg.epfl.ch/~ichim/pdf/avatars_sg2015_paper.pdf) that uses a similar optimization and the author claims that the solution, `x` can be found by solving a `9 * 9` linear system. I have looked into the linear least squares problem but realised that it doesn't work for sum of euclidean norms.
 Can anyone give me an idea as how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, what you should notice

$$\left\lVert x \right\rVert^2_2 = x^Tx $$

then $$\min\limits_x \sum\limits_{i,j}\left\lVert xA_{ij}-b_{ij} \right\rVert^2_2 = \min\limits_x\sum\limits_{i,j}(xA_{ij}-b_{ij})^T(xA_{ij}-b_{ij})$$

or

$$\min\limits_x\sum\limits_{i,j}A_{ij}^Tx^TxA_{ij}-2b_{ij}^TxA_{ij}+b_{ij}^Tb_{ij}$$

according to [cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) $$\frac{\partial a^TXb}{\partial X} = ab^T $$ and $$\frac{\partial b^TX^TXc}{\partial X} = X(bc^T+cb^T)$$

So, you need to take derivative and solve for where it equals to $0$. In the end

$$x \sum\limits_{i, j}A_{ij}A_{ij}^T = \sum\limits_{i, j} b_{ij}A_{ij}^T $$

Comment: Dear @dEmigOd, thank you for your answer. It gave me some direction to think in. But I have a question: In the end, the final expression doesn't seem to be giving us a 9*9 linear system as proclaimed by the author. Isn't it?

Comment: Further, the final expression sums up the product of the knowns, i.e A and b. Hence the result of the sum is  a constant on both the LHS and RHS resulting in something like xa =b or x = b / a. This gives x as a constant whereas x in our domain is a 3 * 9 matrix! @dEmigOd, isn't something wrong there?

Comment: From the question it seems $x$ is an unknown. So i suppose, it is $3 \times 9$ linear equations to solve in the end.

Comment: Thank you @dEmigOd! That clears my doubt. But I still wonder why the author claims that x can be found by solving a 9 * 9 linear system!

Comment: I have implemented using the idea presented by @dEmigOd and got the expected results. One observation: In the end, the $A_{ij}$ terms give a 9 * 9 matrix that is retained even after the summations. Hence we are actually solving a 9 * 9 system. I finally understand the author's claim! Thanks again, @dEmigOd!