# Transpose operations when minimzing the sum of Euclidean norms

Tags: linear-algebra

I found an answer to a question on minimizing the sum of squared Euclidean norms here: [Minimize sum of squared euclidean norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434219/minimize-sum-of-squared-euclidean-norms)

However, there is one step I do not understand:

$$\min\limits_x \sum\limits_{i,j}\left\lVert xA_{ij}-b_{ij} \right\rVert^2_2 = \min\limits_x\sum\limits_{i,j}(xA_{ij}-b_{ij})^T(xA_{ij}-b_{ij})$$

or

$$\min\limits_x\sum\limits_{i,j}A_{ij}^Tx^TxA_{ij}-2b_{ij}^TxA_{ij}+b_{ij}^Tb_{ij}$$

When I expand for the middle term, I have: $$-A_{ij}^Tx^Tb_{ij}- b_{ij}^TA_{ij}x$$

From the transpose rules I do not understand why: $$-A_{ij}^Tx^Tb_{ij}- b_{ij}^TA_{ij}x = -2b_{ij}^TxA_{ij}$$

Is someone able to help?

Answer (score 1):

**First**:

When expanding the middle term, you should have

$$-A_{ij}^Tx^Tb_{ij} -b_{ij}^TxA_{ij}$$ which is not exactly what you have. In fact, $A_{ij}x$ (which you have written) is not even defined, since the dimensions don't match.

---

**Second**:

For a real number $\alpha$, we have $[\alpha]^T=[\alpha]$ (that is, a $1\times 1$ matrix is always symmetric). Also, the matrix $$A_{ij}^Tx^Tb_{ij}$$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix.

Therefore, $$A_{ij}^Tx^Tb_{ij}=(A_{ij}^Tx^Tb_{ij})^T = b_{ij}xA_{ij}.$$